# Moving sequence of statements into macro argument as a block

Tags: coccinelle

This example is a little artificial but it illustrates the problem I am trying to solve with Coccinelle.

Suppose that you want to replace all cases where you lock and unlock a resource with a macro that guards the execution of a list of statements.

For example, you have the code

```c
int main() {
  Handle handle = Lock(resource);
  do_one_thing();
  do_another_thing();
  Unlock(handle);
}
```

and want to replace it with

```c
int main() {
  GUARD(resource, {
    do_one_thing();
    do_another_thing();
  });
}
```

The following rule works fine, but lacks the braces necessary to make this correct:

```
@@
expression expr;
identifier handle;
@@
- Handle handle = Lock(expr);
+ GUARD(expr,
...
- Unlock(handle);
+ );
```

However, when adding braces to make it correct, it fails with an error so that this rule:

```
@@
expression expr;
identifier handle;
@@
- Handle handle = Lock(expr);
+ GUARD(expr, {
...
- Unlock(handle);
+ });
```

Will give the following error:

```
$ spatch --sp-file macro_stmt.cocci example.c
init_defs_builtins: /usr/lib/coccinelle/standard.h
plus: parse error: 
  File "macro_stmt.cocci", line 6, column 14, charpos = 86
  around = '{',
  whole content = + GUARD(expr, {
```

What is causing it and how to fix the rule so that braces are added in the replacement text?

Comment: I would ask on [the Coccinelle mailing list](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/info/cocci); the maintainer, Julia Lawall, is usually fast to answer. I'm not able to say for sure that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, I'm unsure that is possible natively with Coccinelle, but let me propose some ugly workaround in the meantime.

You could use Coccinelle/SmPL to place markers instead of brackets and then rely on `sed` (or something else) to replace those markers with the brackets.

```
@@
expression expr;
identifier handle;
@@
- Handle handle = Lock(expr);
+ GUARD(expr, open_marker,
...
- Unlock(handle);
+ , close_marker);
```

Executed with:

```
spatch --sp-file macro_stmt.cocci example.c \
| sed 's/open_marker,/{/' \
| sed 's/      , close_marker/}/'
```

Comment: Interesting. I was assuming that this would break because there are multiple statements used as parameter to the 'GUARD` function, but it is accepted.

Comment: I [filed an issue](https://github.com/coccinelle/coccinelle/issues/358) and got a response and it seems like this is currently the only option, so I'll accept this as the answer to my question.